# Kubernetes DNS lookg not working from worker node - connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Tags: kubernetes, dns, nslookup

I have build new Kubernetes cluster `v1.20.1` single master and single node with Calico CNI.

I deployed the `busybox` pod in default namespace.

```
# kubectl get pods busybox -o wide
NAME      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP             NODE        NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
busybox   1/1     Running   0          12m   10.203.0.129   node02   <none>           <none>
```

**nslookup not working**

```
kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'
```

cluster is running RHEL 8 with latest update

followed this steps: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/

**nslookup command not able to reach nameserver**

```
# kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup kubernetes.default
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

command terminated with exit code 1
```

**resolve.conf file**

```
# kubectl exec -ti dnsutils -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local 
nameserver 10.96.0.10
options ndots:5
```

**DNS pods running**

```
# kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-74ff55c5b-472vx   1/1     Running   1          85m
coredns-74ff55c5b-c75bq   1/1     Running   1          85m
```

**DNS pod logs**

```
 kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = db32ca3650231d74073ff4cf814959a7
CoreDNS-1.7.0
linux/amd64, go1.14.4, f59c03d
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = db32ca3650231d74073ff4cf814959a7
CoreDNS-1.7.0
linux/amd64, go1.14.4, f59c03d
```

**Service is defined**

```
# kubectl get svc --namespace=kube-system
NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
kube-dns   ClusterIP   10.96.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   86m

**I can see the endpoints of DNS pod**

# kubectl get endpoints kube-dns --namespace=kube-system
NAME       ENDPOINTS                                               AGE
kube-dns   10.203.0.5:53,10.203.0.6:53,10.203.0.5:53 + 3 more...   86m
```

**enabled the logging, but didn't see traffic coming to DNS pod**

```
# kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = db32ca3650231d74073ff4cf814959a7
CoreDNS-1.7.0
linux/amd64, go1.14.4, f59c03d
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = db32ca3650231d74073ff4cf814959a7
CoreDNS-1.7.0
linux/amd64, go1.14.4, f59c03d
```

**I can ping DNS POD**

```
# kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- ping 10.203.0.5
PING 10.203.0.5 (10.203.0.5): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.203.0.5: seq=0 ttl=62 time=6.024 ms
64 bytes from 10.203.0.5: seq=1 ttl=62 time=6.052 ms
64 bytes from 10.203.0.5: seq=2 ttl=62 time=6.175 ms
64 bytes from 10.203.0.5: seq=3 ttl=62 time=6.000 ms
^C
--- 10.203.0.5 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 6.000/6.062/6.175 ms
```

**nmap show port filtered**

```
# ke netshoot-6f677d4fdf-5t5cb -- nmap 10.203.0.5
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-01-15 22:29 UTC
Nmap scan report for 10.203.0.5
Host is up (0.0060s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
53/tcp   filtered domain
8080/tcp filtered http-proxy
8181/tcp filtered intermapper

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 14.33 seconds
```

**If I schedule the POD on master node, nslookup works nmap show port open?**

```
# ke netshoot -- bash
bash-5.0# nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53

Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.96.0.1

 nmap -p 53 10.96.0.10
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-01-15 22:46 UTC
Nmap scan report for kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local (10.96.0.10)
Host is up (0.000098s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE
53/tcp open  domain

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.14 seconds
```

Why nslookup from POD running on worker node is not working? how to troubleshoot this issue?

I re-build the server two times, still same issue.

Thanks

SR

### Update adding kubeadm config file

```
# cat kubeadm-config.yaml
---
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
bootstrapTokens:
- groups:
  - system:bootstrappers:kubeadm:default-node-token
  token: abcdef.0123456789abcdef
  ttl: 24h0m0s
  usages:
  - signing
  - authentication
kind: InitConfiguration
nodeRegistration:
  criSocket: unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock
  taints:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
  kubeletExtraArgs:
    cgroup-driver: "systemd"
---
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: stable
controlPlaneEndpoint: "master01:6443"
networking:
  dnsDomain: cluster.local
  podSubnet: 10.0.0.0/14
  serviceSubnet: 10.96.0.0/12
---
apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: KubeProxyConfiguration
mode: "ipvs
```

"

Comment: Not an expert, but wondering if there is any `netpol` messing up ?

Comment: there are several busybox images with problems when it comes to their installed nettools. can you try again with image busybox:1.28? it might very well not be the issue, but if it is this will help you save a lot of troubleshooting time

Comment: meaningqo is right. You can find out more about this issue on [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/66924)

Comment: tried with `busybox:1.28`  still same error `nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'` if I 
 run busybox on master nslookup works, from worker node its not working.

Comment: How did you deploy Calico ?
Can you check statuses and logs of your `Calico Pods` (especially the one from your worker node) ?

Comment: @matt_j I checked both `calico-node-6tbwh` and `kube-proxy-5l2qb' log no error message. since I was able ping the dns server, network route is good I think.  TCP traffic is not reaching worker node to master node.

Comment: Doesn't the `pods-network-cidr` overlap with the IP range of your VMs ?

Comment: no, my host network is `192.x` pod net work `10.x`. also ping works from pod to pod on different host

Comment: Do you allow connections to TCP and UDP port `53` for DNS access ?
Did you disable `SELinux` ?
Did you bootstrap  k8s using `kubeadm` with default settings + custom `pod-network cidr`?
Is it possible for you to share your exact `pod-network-cidr` and `service-cidr` ?
Do you have any additional cluster configuration e.g. k8s network policy, calico network policy ?
Do you meet these [requirements](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#before-you-begin) ?
Did you follow official docs about installing and configuration k8s with `rhel 8`?

Comment: @matt_j  Yes, SELinux and firewall is disabled,  adeed `kueconfig` file used to setup this cluster. same configuration works with RHEL 7, issue with only RHLE 8.

Comment: Any progress on this ? Stuck in a similar situation.

Comment: @Denn sorry, didn't find any fix for this. I tried `Alan Reed` post step, it didn't work. I also posted another question but didn't get any answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65755990/kubernets-pods-running-on-different-host-not-able-to-establish-tcp-connection

Comment: Do you think it could be the version? I am also on v1.20 but saw this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63653289/kubernetes-nslookup-kubernetes-default-fails and I am thinking of downgrading to v1.19 .what do you think?

Comment: I am also `v1.20.1`, not sure its issue with kubernetes, I  changed to RHEL7 with v1.20.1, nslookup works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, according to the docs - please note that [Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/requirements) and [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/) support **Centos/RHEL 7+**.
In both `Calico` and `kubeadm` documentation we can see that they only support **RHEL7+**.

By default **RHEL8** uses `nftables` instead of `iptables` ( we can still use `iptables` but  "iptables" on **RHEL8** is actually using the kernel's nft framework in the background - look at ["Running Iptables on RHEL 8"](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/5114921)).

> [9.2.1. nftables replaces iptables as the default network packet filtering framework](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_8/networking_considerations-in-adopting-rhel-8)

I believe that `nftables` may cause this network issues because as we can find on nftables [adoption page](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Adoption):

> Kubernetes does not support nftables yet.

**Note:** For now I highly recommend you to use **RHEL7** instead of **RHEL8**.

---

With that in mind, I'll present some information that may help you with **RHEL8**.
I have reproduced your issue and found a solution that works for me.

- First I opened ports required by `Calico` - these ports can be found
  [here](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/requirements) under "Network requirements".
  **As workaround:**
- Next I reverted to the old    `iptables` backend on all cluster
  nodes, you can easily do    so by setting `FirewallBackend`    in
  `/etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf`    to `iptables` as described
  [here](https://firewalld.org/2018/07/nftables-backend).
- Finally I restarted `firewalld` to make the new rules active.

I've tried `nslookup` from `Pod` running on worker node  (kworker) and it seems to work correctly.

```
root@kmaster:~# kubectl get pod,svc -o wide
NAME      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP           NODE      NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/web   1/1     Running   0          112s   10.99.32.1   kworker   <none>           <none>

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE     SELECTOR
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.99.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   5m51s   <none>
root@kmaster:~# kubectl exec -it web -- bash
root@web:/# nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:         10.99.0.10
Address:        10.99.0.10#53

Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.99.0.1

root@web:/#
```

Comment: thanks for the info. let me try this and update the status

Comment: I have changed to RHEL 7

Comment: another post with work around for NFT https://mihail-milev.medium.com/no-pod-to-pod-communication-on-centos-8-kubernetes-with-calico-56d694d2a6f4

Comment: based on this document its support RHEL 8 https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/operations/images.md

Comment: how to fix this issue on ubuntu20?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue setting up a vanilla kubeadm 1.25 cluster on RHEL8 and @matt_j's answer lead me to another solution that avoids nftables by using ipvs mode in kube-proxy.

Just modify the kube-proxy ConfigMap in kube-system namespace so the config.conf file has this value;

```yaml
...
data:
  config.conf:
    ...
    mode: "ipvs"
...
```

And ensure kube-proxy or your nodes are restarted.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, we're using the K3S cluster. And the new agent couldn't make the default(ClusterFirst) DNS query. After lots of research, I found I need to change the `kube-proxy` `cluster-cidr` args to make the DNS work successfully.

Hope this info is useful for others.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by using those arguments to make DNS work?

Comment: I guess it needs to specify the Cluster CIDR to let the `kube-proxy` know the correct IP range, especially since there are multiple network cards in the instance.