# K8S cluster pod can't solve service name if pod on different node from coredns pod

Tags: kubernetes, centos8, calico

I created a k8s Cluster v1.26.0 with `kubeadm` and I am using Calico as CNI. I deploy calico with the helm chart and I followed the steps by the Calico official page and chart.

The container engine is `containerd`.
The nodes Node are Centos 8 and we configured `iptables` in `firewalld` as this thread suggested:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65744565/kubernetes-dns-lookg-not-working-from-worker-node-connection-timed-out-no-ser)

The problem is that when we are trying to run `nslookup` with a dnsutils pod. It does not work. I get a timeout error when the pod tries to reach `kube-dns.kube-system`. If the dnsutils pod is scheduled on the node that runs `coredns`, we can nslookup the service normally. We can ping the pod ip directly but when we try {Service Name}.{Namespace} this doesn't work on any pod that is schedule on a different node than the node running coredns.

We checked all firewall rules required by Calico and all of the required port are open and accessible. We checked `kube-proxy` with `--v=4` and it lists all service names and cluster ip in it.
We checked `iptables` and it seems to have rules like [Debug Service page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-service/) from the official Kubernetes site.

I have struggled on this for 4-5 days now and I really need some suggestions to debug or an understand of that is really going on in our cluster.

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin and networking questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Ok. Understood. Will post a question there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After stuck for a week.
We try to disable firewalld on the node.
Then Everythings work fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're supposed to run coredns on every node. At least, this is how I have all my clusters setup.